# SQL Server 2017, XEvent: sql_text IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, extended-events, logging

I'm attempting to use XEvents to find out which queries are causing my templog.ldf file to grow in size.  I'm getting events, but I see the sizes of the files haven't changed, and that the `sql_text` field is empty.

What I'd like to do is filter my Event so that only events containing a non-null `sql_text` with a LEN() > 0 are logged.  However, I'm not sure how to do this.  When I add the term `sqlserver.sql_text IS NOT NULL` to my filter, I get syntax highlighting that something is wrong.

```
ACTION(...sqlserver.sql_text)
WHERE (
...AND sqlserver.sql_text IS NOT NULL
)
```

So how do I use something like `[sqlserver].[not_equal_i_sql_unicode_string]` to filter out NULLs?  And what is the difference between `[sqlserver].[not_equal_sql_unicode_string]` and the other variants?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Below is the XEvent scrip that I used to spy on the statements that were causing my tempdb to grow.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [TempDbGrowth3] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.database_file_size_change(
ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname,
sqlserver.database_id,
sqlserver.session_id,
sqlserver.sql_text)
WHERE ([database_id]=(2) AND [session_id]>(50))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.databases_log_file_used_size_changed(
ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname,
sqlserver.database_id,
sqlserver.session_id,
sqlserver.sql_text)
WHERE ([database_id]=(2) AND [session_id]>(50)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\Temp\TempDbGrowth3.xel',
max_file_size=(10),max_rollover_files=(10),
metadatafile=N'C:\Temp\TempDbGrowth3.xem')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=1 SECONDS,
MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,
STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Comment: What event you are using when adding this action?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide ``sqlserver.databases_log_file_used_size_changed`` and ``sqlserver.database_file_size_change``

Comment: You are using the wrong action. Please read [Understanding the sql_text Action in Extended Events](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/understanding-the-sql_text-action-in-extended-events/) by Jonathan Kehayias.